# In $R^3, ad_x $ is not diagonalizable

Tags: lie-algebras

I'm doing HW in Lie algebra, there is one question ask me to prove that in $\mathbb R_\text{^}^3$ there is no non-zero element $x$ such that $ad_x$ is diagonalizable. I try to present it in some basis and prove eigenvalues are not in $\mathbb R$ but failed. I couldn't come up with any other thoughts. Can somebody give me some hints?

Thank you.

Comment: I assume that you mean $\Bbb R^3$ with $[x,y] = x \times y$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** One helpful observation is that for all $y$, $(\operatorname{ad}_x^3 + \operatorname{ad}_x)y = 0$.  If $\operatorname{ad}_x$ is diagonalizable over the reals, its only eigenvalue can be $0$.

Comment: The Lie algebra of the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_group_SO(3)) has brackets $[x,y]=z,[z,x]=y,[y,z]=x$, so $ad(x)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & -1\cr 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. But we have $ad(x)^2\neq 0$. So I am not sure.

Comment: @DietrichBurde well... that wasn't so clever of me then. Fixed it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I had stupidly forgotten that we brackets fail to be associative.

Answer (score 1):

The Lie algebra $L$ of the cross product is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{so}_3(\mathbb{R})$, and $ad(L)$ consists of $3\times 3$ real skew-symmetric matrices. 
Since the eigenvalues of a real nonzero skew-symmetric matrix are imaginary it is not possible to diagonalize them over $\mathbb{R}$ - except for the zero matrix.